# adding Bg for Bar button item and tint color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have created a bar button item programatically. Now its looking line simple text . I need to set Background color without border and also need to set tint color programatically.
Here is the code i create a bar button item:

```
UIBarButtonItem *callBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Call Me" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(signUpButtonTapped:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = callBtn;
```

And the background color should: `#F9F9F9`

And the tint color should be :  `00ACC1`

Please help me to do

I need like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Custom Button for to have custom control
Following Code May help

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,60,30);
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor yourColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"Call Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(navigateToDiscussionScreen) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:button.bounds];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[view addSubview:button];
UIBarButtonItem *logoBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:view];
```

Comment: i need to set with left bar button item. And i am getting error in `initwithfram: imageview.bound`  error in imagview

Comment: Don't just copy paste, adjust it for your needs, you may also need to set tint,background and foreground color , Happy coding :)

Comment: no i am new to ios. Thats why dont know should i need to create frame fro my uibutton to show Background color

Comment: Updated, just use colors instead of yourColor, you'll have button as you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99407/discussion-between-arslan-asim-and-user5513630).

Answer (score 1):

In your Appdelegate set Bar tint:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIColor *barColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:172/255.0 blue:193/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor: barColor];
    return YES;
}
```

Now In your View Controller:

```
  UIButton *btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,80,30);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(signUpButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIColor *barColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:172/255.0 blue:193/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    [btn setTitle:@"Call Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitleColor:barColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *callBtn =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = callBtn;
```

Comment: we should not add any code in APPDELEGATE..thats rule for us